# How to set website logo as bookmark icon in android in chrome?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Bookmark icon is showing as first letter of website.

I have tried below changes in head section but none of them is working

1

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="192x192" href="https://matchball.org/images/Png - Only Logo - Variant 3.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

2

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://matchball.org/images/Png%20-%20Only%20Logo%20-%20Variant%203.png" />
```

3

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://matchball.org/images/Png - Only Logo - Variant 3.png" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue has been solved-

1. Chrome shows shortcut icon(or website logo) in bookmarks bar and most recent pages tab if and only if **logo's** size is multiples of 24x24 i.e. 72x72, 192x192 etc.
2. Size of logo must be changed(by cropping or image resize tools) before adding logo reference in href attribute.Styling by css or html woudn't work.
3. As most websites use .png type images which don't have any background so resizing them in paint or naive image editors will add up a white background.In this case [this](http://resizeimage.net/) website proved very helpful for me which can resize images with lossless compression(if a user wish to do so) and without adding background.